# How can I rename all specified file extensions within a folder while preserving the file timestamps?

Tags: windows, powershell, rename

I'm trying to rename the file extensions of a collection .txt files **while also preserving the timestamps**. I first attempted to use [Robocopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy), but this tool can only copy files from one directory to another while preserving file timestamps (file extensions cannot be changed as far as I can tell). I used [PowerRename](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/powerrename), which makes file extension renaming easy, but it also modifies the timestamps of the renamed files.

Finally I used the Windows **MOVE** command to achieve this (as shown below):

```
MOVE "C:\Folder\Filename.txt" "C:\Folder\New_Filename.txt"
```

But I am having trouble doing this with file extensions (specifically renaming multiple files extensions). Because when I attempted to use this code example for my own needs, I came up with this:

```
 Move-Item -Path C:\Users\Elon\Downloads\notes\*.txt -Destination C:\Users\Elon\Downloads\notes\*.md
```

This command responds with the error "Move-Item: Illegal characters in path" - I suspected this is because I used a wildcard on the destination bit maybe? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Could you provide the reason for using `Move-Item` instead of `Rename-Item` for renaming your file ?

Comment: Move-Item won't change the timestamps by default. Or at least this is my assumption. I could easily be wrong about that. Would you recommend using Rename-Item?

Comment: By timestamp do you mean you want to keep the `LastWriteTime` of your files?

Comment: I'm referring to the 'Date Modified' column in Windows Explorer. The files I'm renaming are journal entries. So it's important that they are displayed chronologically in the new tool I'm using to view them (Obsidian). I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try, basically same as Mathias's answer but this uses a `foreach-object` loop so we can capture the `LastWriteTime` **before** we rename the file and then after renaming it we can set the old date to the new file (here is why we use `-PassThru` so we can capture the object that points to the new file).

```
Get-ChildItem ./test/ -Filter *.txt | ForEach-Object {
    $remember = $_.LastWriteTime
    $newName = '{0}.md' -f $_.BaseName
    $newFile = Rename-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName -NewName $newName -PassThru
    $newFile.LastWriteTime = $remember
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Get-ChildItem` to discover the target files, then move one by one:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Users\Elon\Downloads\notes\ -File -Filter *.txt |Move-Item -Destination { "C:\Users\Elon\Downloads\notes\$($_.BaseName).md" }
```

Comment: This still modified the file timestamps actually.